# Android perform analytics request to server

Tags: php, android, mysql, analytics

What would be the best way to track downloads of a app integrated with a sdk. The sdk will hold the methods for sending the request/s.

It will check if a file exists. If the file doesn exist(not downloaded before) it will send a request to a server or use a analytic api to store the datas on a server and create a file(indicate that the app have been downloaded) or any other approach? Data that will be sendt and stored is: downloads based on date, and os version.

Is it possible to use google analytics for this or use any other api, or write own ?

I have basic knowlegde of php and mysql databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at Flurry analytics. They provide a pretty sweet and intuitive SDK. Here's a link to their website: http://www.flurry.com/

I personally use and like their provided API.

PS: Instead of writing code that will do the job of analytics, rather use something that is already established and works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, i will take a look at flurry and google analytics and see what i like

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics APIs to track pageviews events and even send custom variables. [Take a look here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/).